# Should I use an accessor method in delegated method from init?

Tags: objective-c, init, accessor

Should I use accessor methods or access the iVars directly?:

```
- (id)initWithData: (NSData *)someData;
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: someData];
        [parser setDelegate: self];
        [parser parse];
        [parser release];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)parser: (NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement: (NSString *)elementName namespaceURI: (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName: (NSString *)qName attributes: (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    [self setValue: someValue]; // Setting an iVar of self
    [[self value] setOtherValue: otherValue]; // Setting an iVar of an object that's an iVar of self
}
```

Comment: As opposed to what, directly accessing ivars? It doesn't really matter, but the question isn't clear here.

Comment: As opposed to directly accessing them, yes. Sorry I didn't make myself clear. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not safe unless you're very careful. Imagine the following scenario:

```
@interface BaseClass : NSObject
@property (readwrite) NSInteger twists;
@end

@interface SubClass : BaseClass {
    struct something *aField;
}
@end

@implementation BaseClass
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.twists = 100;
        // or
        [self setTwists:100];
    }

    return self;
}

@synthesize twists;
@end

@implementation SubClass
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        aField = malloc(sizeof(struct something));
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    free(aField);
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)setTwists:(NSInteger)value {
    [super setTwists:value];
    aField->twists++;
}
@end
```

If `SubClass` is used, upon instantiation its implementation of `-setTwists:` will be called, which will dereference `aField`. At that point, its initializer has not executed; its superclass' initializer is still executing. The program will crash on the `NULL` pointer dereference.

Comment: This concern of safety is a fair one specifically for the situation of calling accessors from within the initializer, and that problem is not unique to Objective-C. For example, best practices in Java frequently prohibit calling any non-final instance methods from the constructor, just because of the danger that a subclass could override those methods and do something with weird side effects. I don't think, however, that those concerns in general should discourage the general use of accessors from within a class.

Comment: What do you mean with `-twistWidget`? Do you mean `setTwists:`?

Comment: Jim: Whoops, yes. I changed the name of the method halfway through.

Comment: @Tim: They shouldn't discourage it, no--in fact that's a reason to use accessors, to let subclasses in on the system and let them modify behaviour. But during the initializer and the deallocator, they should be avoided.

Comment: Even so, they're not called direclty? I don't call `parser:didStartElement:` myself, it gets called through `[parser parse];` It starts and finished within `init` itself.

Comment: So what? That's just adding an intermediate step. The call to `-setValue:` is still within the scope of `-init`, just further down the trace.

Comment: In theory, your delegate methods could be called by the parser before  the initialization is complete because you invoke the parse method within your initializer. In theory, sending a [self setValue:aValue] from within your delegate method could cause problems if your class is subclassed and the setter is overridden. All of this is possible in theory, and if looking at the design of your class suggests it will be a problem, then don't use accessors at all and just handle all the retain/release manually. In practice, I find using accessors more appropriate most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, I believe you should. Before the advent of @property definitions and some of the newer ARC stuff for memory management it might have been more debatable. However, using things like "@property (retain)" declarations in your header file really help to make sure that retain/release conventions are properly followed, and even automated in the case of ARC.

Comment: But if it were within `init` itself then I shouldn't use accessor methods right?

Comment: I would say that you should proceed with caution before using accessors on self within your initializers. If you're pretty confident that the class won't be subclassed, then it's less of a concern. If you choose not to use an accessor, remember that you are responsible for making sure to retain/release properly. That's something you lose out on if you're not using an auto-generated accessor.

Comment: Sorry for being so confused but if I'm understanding it right, it doesn't matter if the delegate method was called from within `init` or not? It executes directly (literally within `init`)

Comment: Using accessors on objects other than self do not have the same danger. So [parser setDelegate:self] from within your init method is perfectly fine. The only potential danger would be if you did something like [self setValue:someValue] from within your init method because the setValue method could be overridden and run into problems when called from the initializer